# Adding nodes to GameScene from another class

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct, sprite-kit

I have here a struct that's used to pass a function over to GameScene in which I can call whenever needed.

The problem is the line `GameScene.addChild(explosionFirst)` generates the following error:

> 'SKSpriteNode' is not convertible to 'GameScene'

How am I able to add the node from another class to GameScene?

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

struct Explosion {

    var explosions = [SKTexture]()

    mutating func spawnExplosion(spawnPosition: CGPoint) {

        for i in 0...79 {
            let explosion = SKTexture(imageNamed: String(i))
            explosions.append(explosion)
        }

        let explosionFirst = SKSpriteNode(texture: explosions[0])
        explosionFirst.position = spawnPosition
        explosionFirst.zPosition = 1
        explosionFirst.setScale(5)

        GameScene.addChild(explosionFirst)

        let animation = SKAction.animate(with: explosions, timePerFrame: 0.1)

        let scaleIn = SKAction.scale(to: 10, duration: 2.3)
        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)
        let delete = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        let explosionSequence = SKAction.sequence([scaleIn, fadeOut, delete])

        explosionFirst.run(animation)
        explosionFirst.run(explosionSequence)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `GameScene` have a property of type `Explosion`?

Comment: what is `GameScene`?,  I am going to assume that it is your `SKScene` class.  This is not your `GameScene` instance, which would mean that `addChild` is not the correct `addChild` you want to be calling,  `GameScene.addChild(gameSceneInstance,explosionFirst)` would have to be called, but of course, you need to know what `gameSceneInstance` is, and would just call `gameSceneInstance.addChild(explosionFirst)`

Comment: You are right that my GameScene is my SKScene class. How do I create a gameSceneInstance?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ok I created an instance by just doing `var game: GameScene!` then adding the node by saying `GameScene.addChild(explosionFirst)`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: 'GameScene' is a class. You can't add nodes to a class. You can add nodes to an instance of 'GameScene' though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the compiler is seeing `self.GameScene.addChild` and yo don't have a reference to your GameScene object so create one

```
var gameScene : GameScene!
```

**now use:**

```
gameScene.addChild(explosionFirst)
```

Note: by default your initialiser will now have `gameScene: GameScene` so you will have to inject the `Gamescene` dependancy on `init`